# Get values from 5 columns meeting specific conditions from 2 other columns - SQL query in Access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am new here. 
I am using MS-Access and I have a database with several columns. Here is what I have and what I am looking for.

A column has a list of names. There are multiple entries for each name. 
Another column has a list of dates. I should be able to select the most recent date for each of the names.

I know the SQL query for doing this in Access. 
My challenge lies here. I have 5 other columns with status info. Either it's P or F or NA. 
For each name and the most recent date, I should be able to pick the column names from the 5 status columns that equal F (status=fail). 
How do I write a SQL query in Access to do that?

Answer (score 1):

So, I think I got the first part.

```
SELECT O.* FROM data O
INNER JOIN
(SELECT I.[Name], MAX(CreatedDate) As RecentDate FROM data I
GROUP BY I.[Name])I
ON I.[Name] = O.[Name] AND I.RecentDate = O.CreatedDate
```

Now that I think about it, the second part seems very hard to me. The user should be able to select Name and then see the most recent date and the corresponding status column names if the status shows up as "F".